# Global variables aren't visible when testing a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, global-variables

I've 2 scripts, one is testing class, second is the script with functions I want to test.

In the script I want to test, there're many functions that use global variables - these variables are initialized in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, by a function called `init_params()` - initializes around 7 variables. Until here all good. When calling the first function `main()` which calls other functions which also calls other functions sequentially, they use these initialized parameters from `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and they are NOT passed as parameters to these functions - meaning that they're still visible to all the functions in the script without passing them.

The problem arises when I try to test this `main()` function, in the process it shouts that those variables that were initialized aren't declared. I then proceeded to do the `init_params()` inside the `main()` function instead, and still they're not recognized, also tried to initialize it in the test class, and nothing helps. The only thing that I can think of that will work is passing all these 7 variables to every function in the script, which is like 3-4 functions, I can do it and it will work for sure - but it's ugly. And I'm sure there's another way to do it. Any ideas how to make it *less ugly* than my idea?

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
import unittest

from script_i_want_to_test import main, init_params

class TestMul(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_list_int(self):
        """
        bla bla bla
        """
        img_path_fldr = 'path/that/main/needs/as/argument'
        valid_images, total_images = main(img_path_fldr)
        mul = valid_images * total_images
        self.assertEqual(mul, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()



## the script i want to test
def function1():
    #bla bla bla..
    function2()
    ## bla bla bla

def function2():
    # shouts an error here because for example var2 isn't declared

def main(img_path_fldr):
    var1, var2, ..., var7 = init_params(img_path_fldr)
    function1()
    return bla1, bla2
```

Comment: Don't *describe* your code; *show* a minimal example that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Maybe another approach is required. Either move the variables out of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block or use an object oriented approach.

Comment: @chepner I added some code :)

Comment: @Matthias Yes, it does work, but then I need to declare the `img_path_fldr` in my script, what if I want to declare it in my Test Script (see the code I added), and use the path that is declared there? (It's not that critical, but I wonder how it can be achieved effectively, I already thought about some ugly way, would like to know if you have a good way to achieve that, thanks anyways!!)

Comment: Not sure, but what about `script_i_want_to_test.img_path_fldr = ...`.

Comment: `var1` et al. arne't global variables; they are local to `main`. You can declare them as such with `nonlocal var2` inside `function2`, but you are better off passing the necessary values as arguments rather than relying nonlocal or global variables.

Comment: @chepner I see! thank you! But, please note that even when they're declared in the main, they're still visible to function2 although they're declared in the main, and I don't need to pass them. So it's a lil weird :/

Comment: @Matthias Thanks!!! I forgot about it :) Works like a charm

Comment: Actually, my comment isn't correct. `nonlocal` only works if `function2` is *defined* inside `function1` (which would have to be *defined* inside `main`). Variable scopes are defined statically, not dynamically.